# Error while creating resource based policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, resource-based-authorization

Trying to create a resource-based policy and specifying a group as principal but it is failing,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<acc_number>:group/dev-group"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/text.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

It fails with error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, per AWS documentation.

You can specify any of the following principals in a policy:

- AWS account and root user
- IAM users
- Federated users (using web identity or SAML federation)
- IAM roles
- Assumed-role sessions
- AWS services
- Anonymous users (not recommended)

[JSON policy documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)

[AWS support forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=356160)

Comment: Figured it out after digging in the docs.

Strangely, IAM does not allow to use of the "group" as principal.  No explanation why groups arent allowed as an entity.

the AWS document says that

```
You can specify any of the following principals in a policy:

AWS account and root user

IAM users

Federated users (using web identity or SAML federation)

IAM roles

Assumed-role sessions

AWS services

Anonymous users (not recommended)
```

This means "you cannot use the IAM groups as a Principal in a resource-based policy"